# Load settings in dll from file

Tags: .net, settings, app-config

In a class library assembly, I add multiple settings files under properties.

When I add new entries in the settings files, the default values are stored in app.config in the root.
Being an class library assembly it's app.config isn't used. But I would like to use, so I can override the default values from a file.

I know I can copy the content of the class library app.config to the exe's app.config, but I don't want to take the road of having to keep the files manually in sync.

Comment: You should not be using the configuration file for a dll, only a single configuration file can exist for an appliation, the configuration properties are only visible to the project itself.  The solution is not to use a configuration file to set the variables for the dll.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking how to access a config file from a dll that is separate from the executing program's config file? This probably isn't a great idea, but you can create your own version of ConfigurationManager. First, create a class to retrieve settings from your config file (which uses an XmlDocument to parse the config file):

```
public sealed class Settings
{
    private readonly string settingsPath;
    private XmlDocument doc;

    private XmlDocument Doc 
    {
        get
        {
            if (doc == null)
            {
                doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(settingsPath);
            }

            return doc;
        }
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return GetSetting(name);
        }
    }

    internal Settings()
    {
        settingsPath = @"\\path\to\app.config";
    }

    internal Settings(string settingsPath)
    {
        this.settingsPath = settingsPath;
    }

    public string GetSetting(string settingName)
    {
        return Doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("/configuration/settings/setting[@key='{0}']", settingName)).Attributes["value"].Value;
    }
}
```

Then create a helper class:

```
public class SettingsManager
{
    private static Settings settings;

    public static Settings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            if (settings == null)
            {
                settings = new Settings();
            }

            return settings;
        }
    }
}
```

So now you can use the SettingsManager class from a class library like you would the ConfigurationManager from a console application:

```
SettingsManager.Settings["mysetting"]
```

Here is what your config file should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting key="mysetting" value="my value"></setting>
    </settings> 
</configuration>
```